# Cannot set CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED inside the CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

I'm building Googletest as a dependency of my code. Unfortunately Googletest requires very old versions of CMake, which triggers a lot of deprecation warning. I'd like to get rid of them.

I can successfully hide the warnings through command line flags like these:

```
cmake -Wno-deprecated ..
cmake -DCMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED=OFF ..
```

However, I'd prefer to have that set inside the CMakeLists.txt. But I'm not sure how to specify that. The following two commands didn't help:

```
set(CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED OFF)
set(CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED OFF CACHE BOOL)
```

Any ideas? Also, is there maybe a way to have that setting for a limited scope, like e.g. one subdirectory?

Answer (score 3):

Found it out. A little extra flag did the trick:

```
set(CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
```

Not sure though if that's the recommended way to go.

Comment: That's just the syntax, as documented. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html - it's `set(<variable> <value>... CACHE <type> <docstring> [FORCE])
`

Comment: So this line is added in which project's CMakeLists.txt? I presume it's Googletest?