# Disable CMake deprecation warning

Tags: cmake

I'm using a third-party project with `add_subdirectory`, this other project declares `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)`, and with recent CMake I get:

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at External/libmsym/CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.               
                                
  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
```

Since this is a separate project (it's fetched as a git submodule) and I have no write permission, I cannot really fix the problem as suggested. If this was configured through `ExternalProject`, I could use the `PATCH_COMMAND` feature, but I don't think I can do something similar in this situation. Other than creating a fork for this nitpick, is there any other way of disabling this warning or overriding the `cmake_minimum_required` statement in the subdirectory?

EDIT: Apparently `CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED` or `-Wno-deprecated` can do it, but there is some strangeness with the former (it must be saved in the cache for it to work, see [Cannot set CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED inside the CMakeLists.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67432538)), which makes it cumbersome to toggle locally for a particular `add_subdirectory`.

Comment: Have you logged a bug against the upstream project?  Fixed the issue for them and sent a pull request?

Comment: @StephenNewell I have reported it, but I haven't submitted a patch.