# DNEG xStudio Install Cmake Deprecation Warning and CMake Error Failed to ensurepip

Tags: cmake, build, cmake-gui

Currently trying to build DNEG's xStudio locally. I get through all the steps [here](https://github.com/mpkepic/xstudio/blob/windows/docs/build_guides/windows.md) up to configuration in CMake, wherein I encounter the following errors:

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at cmake/modules/vcpkg.cmake:9 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:146 (include)



CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:157 (message):
  Failed to ensurepip.
```

Also, not sure if Qt5_DIR should already be in the CMakeLists.txt file (downloaded from the Academy's xStudio repository), but as it's not, I added an entry separately.

So the configuration isn't working; therefore, can't generate. What part of the configuration am I doing incorrectly?

Update: Tried editing the CMakeLists.txt file version line as indicated [here](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/how-to-fix-cmake-minimum-required-deprecation-warning/2487/3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67432538/cannot-set-cmake-warn-deprecated-inside-the-cmakelists-txt). This got rid of the first CMake Error warning. Now just the 'Failed to ensurepip' error

Update: ended up commenting out the fatal error lines for now; now getting a different error: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:177 (find_package): Could not find a package configuration file provided by "nlohmann_json" with any of the following names: nlohmann_jsonConfig.cmake nlohmann_json-config.cmake Add the installation prefix of "nlohmann_json" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "nlohmann_json_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "nlohmann_json" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed

Comment: whoops, sorry about that. has been corrected